# Добавить код Google Tag Manager на сайт на Magento

Tags: magento

На страницу сайта, который работает на Magento, нужно добавить код в хэд перед `</head>` и в боди после `<body>`. Как это сделать из админки?

Answer (score 0):

Из админки можно вставлять скрипты [тут](http://joxi.ru/4AkvB3BfyzOZq2)

> Система - Конфигурация - Дизайн

Для GT должно быть достаточно, но если нужны переменные в скриптах и т.д. то это уже через код.

Как вариант можно попробовать этот [модуль](https://github.com/evgv/magento-google-dynamic-remarketing)